# Time statistics of a single photon source

Tags: quantum-mechanics

Say I have a single-photon source, and a 100% efficient detector. Can one say what the time-series of clicks of this detector would look like? Does it depend on the frequency distribution of the photons?

And then how would one model this? In QM the state is described by a density matrix (or if it is a pure state by a vector in Hilbert-space), and then how to derive the detection statistik?

Any good citations on these type of problems?

Edit: I am interested in how to model physical system in the framework of quantum mechanics. It is very clear to me how one usually does it. What is not clear is, how emission (time) statistics enters the quantum mechanical description (preparation device is described by a density matrix) and how well it agree experimentally. So to approach this question, the actual first question asked here: can you give an example of the statistic of a single-photon source, I dont mind which one you pick. Then how to encode/derive this statistic from the desitity matrix.

Comment: What are you asking?  Your detector will generate "clicks" every time a photon is emitted, so you can process the time-series to fit to a statistical model of your source.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft so every source has a different statistical model? Do you have an example?

Comment: Do you mean you have a source that emits an *average* of  photons per second for some small number  (e.g. a (very) small black body) and you want to know what the distribution between the times that photons is? e.g. is it a delta at t = ¹⁄ or a Gaussian centred at ¹⁄ but with some non-zero width?

Comment: @lalala I don't understand your question.  Perhaps it'll be easier if you specify (by editing your question) what photon source you are working with.   Apologies for picking on your English grammar, but do you mean a "single-photon" source, i.e. one which rarely if ever emits two photons nearly simultaneously, or do you mean a single object which is a source of photons?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I mean single-photon source

Comment: @JohnRennie I think you got it.  Second part would be how to describe that in the Copenhagen Interpretation of QM.